# iPhone block scope confusion about accessing object references

Tags: iphone, closures, objective-c-blocks

Most of the documented examples of block usage demonstrate closure with simple variables, but I've been confounded by any attempts to access objects which are present in the surrounding code.   For example, this crashes in an ugly, unhelpful way:

```
@interface VisualizerPreset : EyeCandyPreset {
    float changeSourceRate;
    float (^frontPanelSlider2DisplayValueBlock)(void);   
}

....

VisualizerPreset *it;
it = [[VisualizerPreset alloc] init];
it.changeSourceRate = 0.4;

it.frontPanelSlider2DisplayValueBlock = ^(void) {
    return it.changeSourceRate; 
};

....


// this crashes
NSLog(@"%f",it.frontPanelSlider2DisplayValueBlock());
```

Comment: have you tried declaring the referenced variables with __block storage modifier? i.e. __block VisualizerPreset *it;

Comment: Thanks, yeah I tried that, no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that you've lost the block. A block is created in stack, not in the heap. So if you want to keep the block, you have to copy it; this will make a copy of the block in the heap.

float (^aVar) = [^{return 0.0;} copy];

Of course, you will have to also release it later.

Be careful who owns the copy of the block. Inside a block, all referenced objects are automatically retained. So it is easy to create a reference cycle. You can use __block modifier for this problem. Consider reading this http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/

Comment: That was it!   I had declared my block as an "assign" property, not "retain".   The puzzling thing was that it was working fine as long as no variables from the enclosing scope were being referenced.   Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. When you access data that is already released from the memory (a block in this case), the behavior is not defined; it may cause a segmentation fault (crash), reads a bogus thing, or even a correct thing, who knows. That's why it's hard to locate the bug immediately. So when your app behaves strangely, try NSZombieEnabled mode, because it will give you a log when you are accessing a released object.

Comment: Thanks, that's another cool trick.  Also, for the record, it appears that if you're defining a block for use as a property, it's better practice to use "copy" than "retain".   This is what I glean from the doc at any rate, make sense?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes it is. Because a block is allocated in stack, my guess is it WILL be discarded once the stack is released regardless of reference count mechanism (that's as soon as the methods reaches the end of its scope). So you need to make a copy in the heap.